# SharePoint XML Web Part dynamically adding xml link

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

Is there a way to dynamically insert a variable in the `<XMLLink> --variable here--</XMLLink>` tag?

I'm trying to read an URL parameter which will contain the xml files path. What I am trying is to set up my webpart to bring in different xml files dynamically to the same site.

how to do it?

Comment: Can you please share the jquery way of achieveing this? I have similiar need.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this in C# server-side code? If so, this is really easy as the WebPart object itself exposes the XMLLink property.

Client side? No-go. The control renders in the server.

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be client side only. I found a way to do this in JQuery.

Comment: @StevenSalgado I don't suppose you'd like to share how you did this using JQuery? Other users will no doubt find this useful to know.